# 'Or' statement in mongo-db compass

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

[image]

In Mongodb compass. I want to search a collection for the word "LLC" in Both the ownerName and ownerStreet properties (I don't have a text index.) I started with :

```
{ownerName: {$regex: / LLC/i}}
```

which gives 3043 results.

However using:

```
{ownerName: {$regex: RegExp(' LLC')},ownerStreet: {$regex: RegExp(' LLC')}}
```

gives only 100

meaning this is an 'and' statement not an 'or'

How do I use an 'or' statement filter in compass?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operator.

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    {
      ownerName: { $regex: RegExp(' LLC') }
    },
    {
      ownerStreet: { $regex: RegExp(' LLC') }
    }
  ]
})
```

You can even simplify it to

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    {
      ownerName: / LLC/
    },
    {
      ownerStreet: / LLC/
    }
  ]
})
```